# PowerShell how to set clipboard as RTF file contents

Tags: powershell

How to set clipboard as the contents of a rich text format file which may include images

I want to do the same I do with html files here

```
Get-Content "C:\Users\userx\Desktop\clipboardtool\htmlcopy.html" | Set-Clipboard -AsHtml
```

but for .rtf files

Comment: This is just mimicking clip.exe. All PSCore code is OSS so you can go look at the Set-Clipboard source on their Github repo, or locally do this q&d (quick & dirty) approach.   [System.management.automation.proxycommand]::
Create($(New-Object system.management.automation.commandmetadata (Get-Command -Name Set-Clipboard))). Tweaking and or refactoring such code for your use case is a different matter.

Comment: @postanote how would your Q&D approach load the contents of a .rtf file

Comment: It doesn't. I was just pointing you to the source, to see the code of the cmdlet, so, you can directly see its designed capabilities. Remember that Get-Content just pulls the raw data, it does not render it. Unlike clip.exe that has to be running before you use it, it renders as well as the file you want to copy to it, then you are copying the rendered file. Images in an HTML/RTF file is rendered by the browser, MSword, WordPad. No cmdlet native in PowerShell renders a file format outside of text.